# Отключить сообщения Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

Как отключить все сообщения объекта `CreateOLEObject('Word.Application')`?
Дело в том, что я перебираю все документы в папке и конвертирую их в PDF. Но после конвертации остаются диалоговые окна, предлагающие сохранить документы. Как от них избавиться? Нужно, чтобы они не появлялись или игнорировались.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ConvertWordToPDF(aFileName: string);
const
  wdExportFormatPDF = 17;
var
  Doc: OleVariant;
 begin
  FWord := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  try
    FWord.DisplayAlerts := false;
    Doc := FWord.Documents.Open(aFileName, false, true);
    Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Data\'  + FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz', Now) + '.pdf', wdExportFormatPDF);
    Doc := Unassigned;

  except

  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
  FWord := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  try
    FWord.DisplayAlerts := false;
    Doc := FWord.Documents.Open(aFileName, False, True, False); // последний False - не добавлять в список недавно открытых документов
    try
      Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Data\'  + FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz', Now) + '.pdf', wdExportFormatPDF);
    finally
      Doc.Close(False); // False - закрыть без сохранения
    end;
    Doc := Unassigned;
  finally
    FWord.Application.Quit; // закроет висящий в процессах ворд
  end;
except
  // так делать нельзя
end;
```

Comment: Насчет `// так делать нельзя` не совсем понял

Comment: Конструкция `except end;` (без обработки исключения) в большом проекте рано или поздно обернется большой бедой, когда очень много времени будет убито на поиск ошибки/бага. Нужно или что-то делать с исключением или не ловить его.

Comment: я хотел вставить логирование. не дошли руки )